# Complex formed/shaped boxes (with coloured rim/frame and height as specified in \begin{minipage}[height=...])

Tags: boxes, posters

This is the first question I ask. I honestly searched though the topics and I haven't found a solution yet and I even find it difficult to describe in a short title what is looked for in the german language. I think a have a nice idea that also could interest other people and hope that I could articulate what I want to do good enough. So maybe it seems adequate in the end to rename or split the question up or to change the tags. We shall accomplish that.

I want to create a poster and I want to distribute coloured boxes on it. Those coloured boxes shall have an shape that is not rectangular but has more than 4 edges. In my a bit longer MWE I give the code I could already gain. I have reduced as much as I considered to be appropriate. Sry, that the working example is that long. An actual output and an idea how it should look like are attached as images. Here the black lines specify the rims. I think once a syntax is given, I can try to make adjustments by my own again.
Another point, where the comment about splitting may become an issue, is that I did not yet found out how to specify how e.g. with        `\vspace{}` it could be possible to take the remaining part of the height specified in the `minipage` settings.

```
    % !TeX spellcheck = en_EN

    %\PassOptionsToPackage{explicit}{titlesec}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
    \documentclass[portrait,a0]{a0poster}


    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[british]{babel}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{gensymb}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}


    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{hmargin=15mm, bmargin=15mm, tmargin=15mm}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    %\usepackage{graphicx}
    %\usepackage{multicol}
    %\usepackage{parcolumns}
    %\usepackage{showframe}
    %\usepackage{float}
    %\usepackage{amsmath}
    %\usepackage{textcomp}


    %===================================================================
    \definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
    \tcbset{colframe=vssblue, colback=vssblue, coltext=white, before=\adjustbox{valign=c}\bgroup, after=\egroup}%,font=\bfseries}
    \definecolor{vssblue}{rgb}{0,0.4196,0.6745} %blue
    %\DeclareRobustCommand*{\Authorrefmark}[1]{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textsuperscript{\footnotesize #1}}}





    \begin{document}
    %\graphicspath{../Bilder}
    %\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\fbox{}}
    \pagestyle{empty}


    \centering

    {%
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth,margin=0,bgimage=./pics/TU_building_300}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[height=4cm,width=0.8\textwidth]%
        \centering%\color{white}%
        {
        \begin{spacing}{1.1}\LARGE\bfseries\addtolength\baselineskip{1mm} Analysis of short range phenomena in two novel materials using the PDF-method\end{spacing}
        }%
        \end{tcolorbox}%
        \hspace{3mm}
        \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
        {\centering\hspace{-1mm}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../Bilder/XRCLogo.png}}%
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
        \vspace{5mm}\large\bfseries\uline{Philipp Hans}\textsuperscript{a}, Klaudia Hradil\\[2mm] %
            X-ray Center - TU Wien%
        \end{minipage}
    \end{adjustbox}\\[5mm]%
    }%


    \begin{minipage}[t][0.4\textheight][t]{1\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
    \centering
        \begin{minipage}[t][1\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
        \centering
            \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,colframe=green!40!black,fontupper=\color{black},title=\large Beispiel 1: Strukturänderung in Folge einer Amorphisierung: Mit TiO\(_2\) beschichtete Si-Partikel - Eine Messung vom Synchrotron]
                \centering  
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{
                \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{}
                    \captionof*{figure}{x}
                \end{minipage}%
                \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \centering  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{}
                    \captionof*{figure}{c}
                \end{minipage}}
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{
                    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \lipsum[3]
                    \end{minipage}}%

                \adjustbox{valign=t}{
                    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{../Bilder/allesgr.png}
                    \captionof*{figure}{a}
                    \end{minipage}}%
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{
                    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{../Bilder/difplt_verglTiO2.png}
                    \captionof*{figure}{b: \AA}
                    \end{minipage}}%
                \vspace{18cm}
    %           \hfill
            \end{tcolorbox}%
        \end{minipage}%
    %
    \hfil
    %
        \begin{minipage}[t][1\textheight][t]{0.3\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
            \section*{What's it all about?}
            \lipsum[1-3]

            \begin{thebibliography}{3}
                \scriptsize
    %           \begin{multicols}{2}
                    \bibitem{IEEEhowto:Key}
                        Debye, P.: ”Zerstreuung von R\"ontgenstrahlen”. - \hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Annalen der Physik, 1915, 351, pp. 809-823\vspace{-0.3cm}

    %           \end{multicols}
            \end{thebibliography}
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \vfil


    \begin{minipage}[0.60\textheight]{\textwidth}%\vspace{0pt}
        \centering
            \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,colframe=green!40!black,fontupper=\color{black},title=\large Beispiel 1: Strukturänderung in Folge einer Amorphisierung: Mit TiO\(_2\) beschichtete Si-Partikel - Eine Messung vom Synchrotron]
                \centering  
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{
                \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{}
                    \captionof*{figure}{x}
                \end{minipage}%
                \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                        \centering  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{}
                        \captionof*{figure}{c}
                \end{minipage}}
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{
                    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \lipsum[3]
                    \end{minipage}}%

                \adjustbox{valign=t}{
                    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{../Bilder/allesgr.png}
                    \captionof*{figure}{a}
                    \end{minipage}}%
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{
                    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{}
                    \captionof*{figure}{b: \AA}
                    \end{minipage}}%

                \adjustbox{valign=t}{
                    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}
                    \captionof*{figure}{b}
                    \end{minipage}}
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{
                    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{}
                    \captionof*{figure}{c}
                    \end{minipage}}
                \adjustbox{valign=t}{
                    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                    It is very difficult to give an outlook how the results will be. It is planned to do a reverse monte carlo (RMC) refinement of 
                    trying to fit the experimental PDF in the best possible way. This is planned to do using the program DIFFEV[note].

                    As it is an amorphous sample,
                    \end{minipage}}

            \vspace{27cm}
            \hfill

            \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{minipage}
    %\enlargethispage{4cm}

    \vfill
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    ECM29 - European Crystallographers Meeting 2015 in Rovinj/Croatia
    \end{minipage}%

    \end{document
```

[image: Actual output of the mwe]
[image: Desired output]

I would be thankful if someone helps me a bit further herewith. Also tips about programming style or other explainations are very welcome if he or she has time to give such.

Philipp

PS: I haven't got enough reputation for creating new tag-expressions. My suggestions would be the following: complex-shaped-boxes distributing-objects frames-around-boxes. If someone finds this good, maybe the person can do this. I think this are good words for finding the corresponding subject.